# MPMoviePlayerController Fullscreen mode doesn't actually display over the entire screen

Tags: iphone, video, screen, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've implemented video play functionality within my app, and everything is working perfectly, except for this one issue.  Whenever the fullscreen toggle button is tapped, or if you double-tap the screen, this of course is meant to toggle the video from being played in it's natural wide screen state (black is seen above and below the video) to a zoomed state, where the video takes up the entire screen of 480x320.  For me, the video adjusts slightly in size, but doesn't come close to taking up the entire screen.  This works correctly in almost every app I can think of that plays videos, such as Fandango, YouTube, etc.

In this zoomed mode, of course you're losing part of the picture, because it's actually off the screen, since the only way to render a 2.40:1 image on the full screen while still maintaining aspect ratio is to zoom.  Again, every other app I can think of works this way, but it's not working for me.

So, I have tried everything I can think of to get this full screen zoomed feature to work, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the platform  for your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, it appears that this is due to the format/encoding of the video itself.  I don't know specficis, however.  I just know that depending on which video is being played, this feature may or may not work.